# How to mix QStandardItemModel

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I made a TreeView using QStandardItemModel like below **image A**

[image]

and I also have a QStandardItemModel like below **image B**

Now, I want mix two Model together to made a new Model for a TreeView
[image]

new TreeView has like below **image C**:

[image]

Example:

```
QStandardItemModel * fileTree = new QStandardItemModel();
QStandardItemModel * zipTree = new QStandardItemModel();
QStandardItemModel * fullTree = new QStandardItemModel();
......
......
```

fileTree is model for TreeView image A;

zipTree is model for TreeView image B;

How to mix them to make fullTree for TreeView image C.

**update:**

3 data have both a model, only data is different. I want to merge data for photo C form A + B. file a.zip -> folder a. and add file list of a (image B) to new folder (a)

**P/S: Don't using QfileSystemModel**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QTreeView t;
QStandardItemModel a;
t.setModel(&a);
t.show();
```

I simplified the `Image A`, construct it as below:

```
QStandardItem* folder1 = new QStandardItem("folder1");
QStandardItem* zip = new QStandardItem("a.zip");
a.appendRow(folder1);
folder1->appendRow(zip);
```

Construct `Image B`:

```
QStandardItemModel b;
b.appendRow(new QStandardItem("filea"));
b.appendRow(new QStandardItem("fileb"));
b.appendRow(new QStandardItem("filec"));
```

*"Mix"* both as `Image C`:

```
zip->setText(zip->text().remove(".zip"));
for (int i = 0; i < b.rowCount(); i++) {
    zip->appendRow(b.takeItem(i));
}
```